# Multidimensional Array key reference

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that gives me this:

```
            [ShipmentServiceLevelCategory] => test
            [OrderTotal] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 11.11
                    [CurrencyCode] => GBP
                )

            [ShipServiceLevel] => Std UK Dom
            [MarketplaceId] => test
            [ShippingAddress] => Array
                (
                    [Phone] => 123213213213
                    [PostalCode] => TES T12
                    [Name] => Test
                    [CountryCode] => GB
                    [StateOrRegion] => Test
                    [AddressLine1] => Test
                    [City] => Test
                )
```

I want to insert this information into my DB but my column names are different from the array keys so I am trying to create another array that contains the key mappings. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$map = array('ShippingAddress['Phone']' => 'DEL_PHONE','ShippingAddress['PostalCode']'=> 'DEL_POSTCODE','ShippingAddress['Name']' => 'DEL_NAME');
```

However this gives me a syntax error, can somebody point out where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: what are your columns names?

Comment: My column names are DEL_PHONE, DEL_POSTCODE etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$map = array('ShippingAddress' => array (
'Phone' => 'DEL_PHONE',
'PostalCode' => 'DEL_POSTCODE',
'Name' => 'DEL_NAME' 
) );
```

Comment: This works but this also means I'll have to create a different mapping array for the other column reference (OrderTotal)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax to get current array values and use them in different array

`$new_array = array();`

`$new_array['DEL_PHONE'] = $current_array['ShippingAddress']['Phone'];`

`$new_array['DEL_POSTCODE'] = $current_array['ShippingAddress']['PostalCode'];`

That should give you a good idea on how to continue

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array like this:

```
define("DEL_PHONE", "col1");
define("DEL_NAME", "col2");
$attributes = array(
DEL_PHONE => $data['ShippingAddress']['Phone'],
DEL_NAME => $data['ShippingAddress']['PostalCode']
);
```